# Symfony 4 - Problems installing Bundles

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I try to install a bundle for barcodes, but I get an error, perhaps somebody could help me:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for __root__ dev-master -> satisfiable by __root__[dev-master].
    - alpin11/twig-barcode v1.0 requires symfony/symfony ^3.4 || ^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.10 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.11 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.3 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.4 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.5 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.6 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.7 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.8 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.9 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.0 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.1 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - symfony/symfony v4.3.2 conflicts with __root__[dev-master].
    - Installation request for alpin11/twig-barcode ^1.0 -> satisfiable by alpin11/twig-barcode[v1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "endroid/qr-code-bundle": "^3.3",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.11",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.3",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^5.0",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.11",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "security-checker security:check": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/console": "^4.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "composer show twig/twig" and verify you are using Twig 3.0.  If so, contact the authors of the barcode bundle and see if they plan to support it.

Comment: Nothing to do with Symfony or “bundles”. Just don’t install bad software.

Comment: @Cerad I have Version v2.12.5

Comment: @emix Why bad software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should complain to the provider of that package for making a bad decision: the package enforces the installation of `symfony/symfony` (the full package of all Symfony components), while all current projects should depend on the individual components. That's what your project does: it installs each **needed** component, and not the whole framework.

And that's where stuff gets difficult for you: the full framework package `symfony/symfony` contains all components and lists them in the `replaces` section. Installing both the framework package **and** single components leads to problems and is not possible. But as that barcode package depends on the whole framework, and your own application depends on single components, the installation can not continue.

If you really want to use this package (there might be alternatives that structure their dependencies better), you can remove all Symfony components (those with the version constraint `4.3.*`) from your `composer.json` and instead require `symfony/symfony:4.3.*`. Afterwards, that package should be installable